# How to add a link similar to whatsapp in android phone book contacts

Tags: android

I need help . I would like to know how to add a link similar to Whatsapp in android phone book contacts. I am looking at `ContentProviders` , but its more like adding a field. But as my requirement is for a link (ex: can open a website related to that contact person) .

Thx
Krishna